# How can dynamically create upstream block with Openresty and Lua?

Tags: nginx, lua, nginx-config, openresty

I need to create an `upstream` block in the `default.conf` dynamically with **Openresty** and **Lua**.

```
upstream my_gateway{

    for server in #SERVERS_ENV:
       server xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:yyyy  max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`ngx.balancer`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-core/blob/master/lib/ngx/balancer.md) is what you are looking for.